# /UploadEX.aspx is displaying seemingly random characters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a situation in which the _layouts/UploadEX.aspx is displaying seemingly random characters as shown below. The Farm is SharePoint 2010 SP1.

I'm not sure where the strings in the image( 77e, 20 and 105.0) are coming from. Its only happening in the sites for one webApplication. The Site does not have a custom Upload Page associated with it.

Anyone ever seen this before and know how to stop it. Some of the strings are getting inserted into javascript code and are causing it to break.

It's happening 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a network issue.

Do you know if traffic to your SharePoint environment being routed through a load balancer? To confirm that the problem is stemming from the network, try updating your computer's host file so that requests for your SharePoint URL are routed directly to one of your SharePoint web servers; if the problem goes away, you'll know that the problem was coming from the network and not from the web server.

You should work with whatever team manages your network to understand why characters might be getting inserted into HTTP responses. Use a tool like Fiddler to trace the http requests and responses to identify the exact moments when the data gets garbled.

Edit: **What fixed the problem was removing HTTP Compression and Caching profiles from the load balancer.**

Comment: I am in a load balanced environment, and when I put an entry in my hosts file the issue went away. I took the entry out of my hosts and the problem reappeared. So I went onto the server and ran a wireshark,. Looking at the traffic sent out I am seeing the odd characters are being sent out by sharepoint, but ONLY if it comes thru the load balancer. Very confusing.....

Comment: @russellg what fixed this problem for us was disabling caching and http compression in the load balancer settings

Comment: thanks for the feedback triggle. I was thinking it was some custom code in  my current environment. if you have seen this in your environment as well then I am looking in the wrong place. will need to try your suggestions above.  thanks!

Comment: We removed the HTTP compression and caching profiles from the load balance and it resolved the issue.. Thankyou for your help!